# setting the children of ViewFlipper at centre

Tags: android, viewflipper

I am adding dynamic text view to view flipper like below.
Everything is working perfectly, but how can i center each text view at center of View Flipper, i have looked for the gravity option but i think it doesn't support. As the text view contains different text length i want every text view to be at center of view flipper.

```
 for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    vf.addView(tv, i);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I want textview to be at centre of viewflipper.

Answer (score 3):

I think this may help :

```
    ViewFlipper flipper = new ViewFlipper(this);

    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textView.setText("Hello World");

    flipper.addView(textView);
    setContentView(flipper);
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about gravitiy we can set this way, or a layout gravity you have tried actually?

```
tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

Comment: But i want children of viewflipper to be at the centre.

Comment: Have you anywhere written that you want Childen of ViewFlipper instead of TextView?

Comment: TextView are the children of viewflipper, i have submitted the sample code.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set ViewFlippers width in xml as

```
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

I had an similar problem and this worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way,

```
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        param.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        tv.setLayoutParams(param);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got the answer, actually you need to add linearlayout to viewflipper then add children to linearlayout with giving gravity parameter to linear layout.

Comment: Even though what you did would have worked out. But it burdened the layout tree of yours. A better way of doing it would have been to set layout_gravity value of your TextView to center.